# view reviews of a book using conditional logic to determine which reviews to display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a book review/online book group app.

On the individual book show page, I would like to have the user decide whether or not they would like to see reviews, reviews with spoilers or all of it. Therefore when the page loads they should see only the main info about the book, and three buttons: `See Reviews`, `See Spoilers`, `See All`.

Now this seems like it should be a totally easy task. If I were using JS and jQuery, I would just hide all the elements and have the buttons trigger jQuery shows if they match the objects spoiler code, however this does not work in Rails.

I have tried doing js in the view, I have tried running the logic through their own routes, I've tried functions in the controller and helper and nothing works!! Auuugghh! I've been working on this for almost 2 days and want to smash my computer in. Granted, this is my first project back on Rails after 6 months off, I've been working mostly in Node, and my Rails is rusty. Here's the code that may be pertinent, but it's Rails so it's all over the place so it might just be easier to look at the github repo, which is here. https://github.com/nwimmer123/readit_rails

I've been cruising StackOverflow and reading APIDock, but haven't been able to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

show.html.erb

```
  <div class="container">
    <%= button_to "Show Reviews", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-2" %>
    <%= button_to "Show Spoilers", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-2" %>
    <%= link_to "Show It All", controller: "books", method: "find_reviews", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-2"%>

  </div>

<% if @show_the_reviews == true %>
    <div class="container">
      <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
        <% if review.book_id.to_s == params[:id].to_s %>
        <div class="review">
          <div>
            <strong><%= review.user.name %></strong>
            <% if review.spoiler == "1" %>
              <span class="center-text">SPOILER</span>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <p><%= review.body %></p>
          <button class="pull-right">Respond</button>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

books controller

```
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @reviews = Review.all       
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :genre, :image, :publication_date, :publisher, :synopsis)
  end

  def current_book
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def find_reviews
    puts "LOOK HERE!!!!!!"
    @reviews.each do |review|
      if review.book_id.to_s == params[:id].to_s
        puts review.spoiler
      end
    end
    @show_the_reviews = true
   redirect_to book_path(@book.id)
  end

end
```

When I click Show It All, it redirects to home page?!

Note, I realize this question is poorly written and vague, but I'm super annoyed and can't figure out how to write it better. I think I'm looking for basic strategies here.

Comment: why can't you just use javascript? you can use javascript with rails views.

Comment: You need to edit your question. It is rude to us that you acknowledge it's poorly written/vague, and that you aren't putting forward the effort to fix it. Everyone reading has to trudge through it to help you. You can show/hide buttons with javascript and/or Jquery and implement it with rails. Your issue might be with turbolinks, in which case you should read the last section of the rails turbolinks guide.

Comment: toddmetheny - when I tried js, I couldn't figure out how to identify wether or not the review was a spoiler since that attribute is an item of the reviews model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with jQuery, just give the reviews an appropriate class..

```
<% review_class = review.spoiler == true ? ' spoiler' : ' spoiler-free' %>
<div class="review <%= review_class%>">
```

Then put some `<script>` at the top of the view that will toggle show/hide for `$('.spoiler')` and `$('.spoiler-free')` and have your buttons `onclick` call the js functions.

You can do it in pure rails by making a field-less form with submit buttons, and in the called action test `params[:commit]` which will have the text of the button that was clicked, and then use that in conditional logic to filter out whether you retrieve spoiler reviews, non-spoiler reviews, or both.  But the jQuery is way more responsive.

Comment: Thanks Steve, My main quandary in using js was how to identify wether the item was a spoiler or not since i had identified it as such via an attribute, spoiler, in the model and I haven't figured out how to use jQuery to check a database object attributes. I'll give this a try a see if I can make it work.

Comment: yes, well  by using the database attribute to add a class to the div (as my answer suggests) that should solve it.  Cheers Steve